# Number of complete directed graphs with equal in- and out-degrees

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, permutations

What is the number of complete directed graphs with $7$ labelled vertices such that every vertex has an in- and out-degree equal to $3$? The total number of directed graphs possible is $2^{21}$, because there are two possible values for the $21$ edges. I am not sure how to proceed after selecting the initial node and saying that its three out-neighbours can be chosen in  $_6C_3$ ways.

Comment: From your total count, it seems that you're thinking of labeled vertices? And why does the title say "regular polygons"?

Comment: You didn't respond to the question about labeled vertices?

Comment: @joriki: Yes they are labelled.

Answer (score 1):

After your initial choice of $\binom63$, you can connect each group of three among themselves either in a cycle (with $2$ different orientations) or with a source, a link and a sink (with $6$ different assignments of the roles).

Of the $9$ edges between the two groups of three, $3$ have to go in one direction and $6$ in the other, so they're fixed if we choose the $3$. There are $6$ ways to connect two cycles, $3$ ways to connect a cycle and a source-link-sink arrangement and $1$ way to connect two source-link-sink arrangements. That makes a total of

$$
\binom63\left(6\cdot2\cdot2+2\cdot3\cdot2\cdot6+1\cdot6\cdot6\right)=20\cdot132=2640
$$

different graphs.